# corner radius issue

Tags: jquery-mobile

i'm trying to edit the default corner radius of 0.6em to 1px. But the changes are not reflecting. I'm trying to change the radius in .ui-corner-all & .ui-corner-left
Here is the link to my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/PtLKF/40/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have firebug, or some other in browser debugger, you can see that all you css is being overwritten by JQuery Mobile's css. You can try either 1) renaming the classes to non-jquery class names, or b) using `!important`

If that doesn't work then use firebug to find where the issue is being caused with JQuery's css and edit those methods in your css file to overwrite it